# Jenkins prometheus plugin not showing data on endpoint

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

My `Jenkins - 2.263.1(LTS)` deployed through tomcat and i have installed `Prometheus metrics plugin - 2.0.8` and restarted the service.

My jenkins base URL - `http://jenkins-server:8080/jenkins`

But my `prometheus` end-point - `http://jenkins-server:8080/jenkins/prometheus` not showing any metrics data.

I have added below in my `prometheus.yml`

```
  - job_name: 'jenkins'
    metrics_path: '/jenkins/prometheus'
    scheme: http
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['jenkins-server:8080']
```

Currently `LDAP authentication` and `Project-based Matrix Authorization` configured. Also i have tried with domain credential `password` and `token` in my `prometheus.yml` but still it doesn't show the plugin generated data in my end-point. Just shows the blank page on my browsers(IE and Chrome).

```
basic_auth:
  username: domain-user-id
  password: 98qw37asdkdsjfeiq1dedsewe
```

**Curl response**

```
$ curl -v jenkins-server:8080/jenkins/prometheus
*   Trying 206.25.26.27...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to jenkins-server (206.25.26.27) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /jenkins/prometheus HTTP/1.1
> Host: jenkins-server:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 302
< Cache-Control: private
< Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Location: /jenkins/prometheus/
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Wed, 17 Feb 2021 11:42:00 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host jenkins-server left intact 


$ curl -X GET jenkins-server:8080/jenkins/prometheus/
$ curl -X GET http://jenkins-server:8080/jenkins/prometheus/
```

Empty response for above commands. Please share some pointers to resolve this issue. thanks in advance.

@poshak, Generated access key and tired on my browser with `https://jenkins_ipaddres:portnumber/jenkins/metrics/accesskey` Now i can able to view the below.

[image]

[image]

Is these data is enough for promethues?

Comment: Try to change the following configuration: "metrics_path: '/prometheus'" and "- targets: 'jenkins-server:8080'/jenkins".

Comment: `- targets: ['jenkins-sever:8080'/jenkins]` and `- targets: ['jenkins-sever:8080/jenkins']` showing `is not a valid hostname` error.

Comment: `"- targets: 'jenkins-server:8080'/jenkins"` same result.

Comment: The ' must be at the end of the line: - targets: 'jenkins-server:8080/jenkins'

Comment: tried still same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an Jenkins Prometheus plugin issue. After upgrading it to `2.0.9` issue solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate Access Keys in the metrics section and access the url **https://jenkins_ipaddres:portnumber/metrics/accesskey** you would now be able to view the metrics.

Path to generate the Access Keys:

Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure Systems > Metrics >> Add >> Generate >> Save

Thanks

Comment: Updated comments added in the question, Please have a look once and suggest.